Adding a suffix to joined columns in Snowflake
I have two CTEs with several metrics for two different time periods in Snowflake. I want to create a table with these metrics by joining these CTEs and appending a suffix to the columns to identify the time period. Yes, some joins will produce a _2 suffix for the second CTE, but I want to control this.
How can I achieve a result like the following directly in the query without having to manually alias every column?



user_id
c1_cte1
c2_cte1
c1_cte2
c2_cte2




user1
value
value
value
value


user2
value
value
value
value




It is possible to achieve it using Snowpark:

snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.join

lsuffix – Suffix to add to the overlapping columns of the left DataFrame.
rsuffix – Suffix to add to the overlapping columns of the right DataFrame.


Code:
import snowflake.snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
session = get_active_session()

df_cte1 = session.sql("SELECT 1 AS user_id, 'a' AS c1, 'b' AS c2")
df_cte2 = session.sql("SELECT 1 AS user_id, 'y' AS c1, 'z' AS c2")

df = df_cte1.join(df_cte2, on = ["user_id"], lsuffix = '_cte1', rsuffix = "_cte2")
df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("TEST.PUBLIC.RESULT")

Output:


Behind the scene SQL looks as follow(Query History):


Thank you, but I am looking for a solution that can go directly in the query. I might have to use a dbt macro.
